# Pass different array to onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I want to pass different array value to onclick function, when click on the button show the result. My expected result when click on the first "Show" button should be 4 and 5, the second "Show" button should be 5 and 6. But my code only show 5 and 6 for the first and second button, how can I get the expected result?

```
<table name="itemTable" id="itemTable" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th style="width:5%"></th>
    <th style="width:5%"></th>
    <th style="width:50%">2</th>
    <th style="width:10%">3</th>
    <th style="width:15%">4</th>
    <th style="width:15%">5</th>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var member_data= [];//if declare here, all all of the row get the latest id
addrow(1);
addrow(2);

function addrow(branch_id){
    //var member_data= [];//if declare here will show "member_data is not defined"
    member_data= [];
    member_data.push({
        phone: 123,
        name: "aaa",
        id: 3 + branch_id
    });
    member_data.push({
        phone: 456,
        name: "bbb",
        id: 4 + branch_id
    });

    ttt(branch_id,member_data);
}

function ttt(branch_id,member_data){
    var table = document.getElementById("itemTable");
    var tableRow = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(tableRow);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

    cell1.innerHTML = 
                    '<button type="button" onclick="show_member(member_data)">Show</button>'//this line of show "member_data is not defined"
                    + '<input type="text" name="branch" value="'+branch_id+'">';
}

function show_member(aaa){
    for (var i = 0; i < aaa.length; i++) {
        //console.log(aaa[i]);
        alert(JSON.parse(aaa[i].id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My expected result when click on the first "Show" button should be 4
>   and 5, the second "Show" button should be 5 and 6. But my code only
>   show 5 and 6 for the first and second button.

Because by the time onclick was invoked, member data got changed since it is defined globally and its value is updated for every new button.

Change your `addRow` method to following so that `member_data` now contains data for all branches

```
function addrow(branch_id){
    member_data= [];
    member_data[branch_id].push({
        phone: 123,
        name: "aaa",
        id: 3 + branch_id
    });
    member_data[branch_id].push({
        phone: 456,
        name: "bbb",
        id: 4 + branch_id
    });

    ttt(branch_id,member_data);
}
```

similarly `ttt` as

```
function ttt(branch_id,member_data){
    var table = document.getElementById("itemTable");
    var tableRow = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(tableRow);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

    cell1.innerHTML = 
                    '<button type="button" onclick="show_member(member_data, '+ branch_id +')">Show</button>'//this line of show "member_data is not defined"
                    + '<input type="text" name="branch" value="'+branch_id+'">';
}
```

and finally show_member as

```
function show_member(aaa, branchId){
    for (var i = 0; i < aaa[branchId].length; i++) {
        //console.log(aaa[i]);
        alert(JSON.parse(aaa[branchId][i].id));
    }
}
```

Comment: i follow the addrow, and it show "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: @Arzozeus sorry, add this before pushing `member_data[branch_id]= [];`

Comment: Thank you @gurvinder372, I am able to get what I want, thanks alot